# How to use a textarea to get the csv file /delimited data?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like to use a textarea in html form to get the delimited data

for example:
The simple data is like the following

```
testA@testa.com peter USA 
testB@testB.com Tony USA 
testC@testC.com tom USA 
testA@testa.com peter USA
testA@.com peter USA
```

The problems are:

1. How to check where is each line ends? (\n)?
2. How to do duplication checking (only for email)? (if 3 data each row, get 1,4,7,11...data, and array_unique?)
3. Should i restrict the deliminator symbol or i do something to check automatically?
4. What If space is deliminator , but at same time my other data eg. is using space  e.g. Tony Hanks ?

Thank you for any kind of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would split string by line ends:

```
$r = explode(PHP_EOL, $data); //data is your raw data from textarea
```

To check the delimiter, explode first line by all delimiters that are possible and check array count.

```
foreach( array(' ', ';', '/') as $delimiter) {
  $x = explode($delimiter, r[0]);
  if(count($x) == 3) {
    break;
  }
}
```

After that use proper delimiter with str-getcsv on raw data: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

> What If space is deliminator , but at same time my other data eg. is using space e.g. Tony Hanks ?

In that case you need to use quotes. Excel also could not handle this without quotes.

> How to do duplication checking (only for email)?

Create array where keys are emails. Iterate through your parsed csv and check if key isset already or not.